# How to add elements to a sorted redis set in python

Tags: python, django, redis

I have a Django app where users upload photos for the general public to see and comment on. One requirement is that the uploaded photo must not be something the website has already seen recently. To accomplish this, I calculate the [average (perceptual) hash](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2013/11/26/image-hashing-with-python/) of every image presented for uploading, saving it in the DB. Later, when a new image is being put up, it's average hash is compared to the same of 1000 most recent images.

Now, I want to make this process faster by saving the most recent avg hashes in a **sorted redis set**, instead of my Postgresql DB.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this. First step would be building a set of avg hashes to compare against, ensuring the set size remains at 1000, and contains the latest 1000 kay-value pairs.

How would the code look like?

```
import redis

POOL = redis.ConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db=0)

def insertValue(photo_hash):
    my_server = redis.Redis(connection_pool=POOL)
    try:
        size = my_server.zcard("my_set")
        if size < 1001:
            my_server.zadd("my_set", int(time.time() * 1000), photo_hash)    #time.time() equals seconds since epoch
        else:
           #zrem the element with the lowest score, and then ...
           my_server.zadd("my_set", int(time.time() * 1000), photo_hash)    
    except:
        my_server.zadd("my_set", int(time.time() * 1000), photo_hash)
```

**Firstly**, is the syntax for `zadd` correct (I can't find online python examples approximating what I'm trying to do), and **secondly**, how does one `zrem` the element with the lowest score from a sorted set?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [zadd](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis.Redis.zadd) is a bit tricky.

> NOTE: The order of arguments differs from that of the official ZADD
>   command. For backwards compatability, this method accepts arguments in
>   the form of name1, score1, name2, score2, while the official Redis
>   documents expects score1, name1, score2, name2.
>
> If you’re looking to use the standard syntax, consider using the
>   StrictRedis class. See the API Reference section of the docs for more
>   information.

Since you are not using StrictRedis what your code above doess is add an element named `time,time()*1000` into the set named `my_set` with a value of `photo_hash` which seems to be fine. Because you have both a `zrank` and a `zscore` function which allows you to check for existence either by a name or by a value. These operations are very fast. Much faster than using memcached where you would need to fetch the entire set before hand.

Similarly for removing elements, you can either use `zremrangebyrank` or `zremrangebyscore` so in essence what you choose to be the value and what you choose to be the name and what you choose to be the value aren't really important provided that both are unique. And in your case they can both be unique.

The only improvement that I can see is to use the image's primary key instead of time. Since it's possible that two persons may upload an image at the same time.

Comment: Hey again! Actually I realized I was trying to *guess* the python implementation while looking at redis' own docs - I should have been looking at redis-py docs for this. I've read about `zrank`, `zscore`, `zremrangebyrank` and `zremrangebyscore`. So to get rid of extra set members if a set is overflowing my pre-set 1000 size, I'll get the cardinality (size) of the set, and then use `zremrangebyrank(my_set, 1000, size)`?

Comment: yes, that's pretty much it. However because redis sets are blazing fast you don't need to worry about the deletion too much but what you have said in the comment works

Comment: Well, I do want to delete after a while because while I don't want users to re-upload recently uploaded photos, it's okay if they do it after a day or two. Recycling content is a fact of life on websites like 9gag (or mine). Thanks for the tip, I just hope I can move a bunch of other stuff onto redis too. FAST is good, plus you've seen my website, it's more of a user timeline, for which I feel redis is more suited as a backend than postgresql. But of course, need to dig much much deeper.

Comment: redis in most cases is a compliment to postgres, but it's definitely a replacement for memcached. Whatever memcached does redis can do better

Comment: A followup clarification: I'm currently using two functions - called one after the other - where I manipulate some aspect of a sorted set. It's working fine. At the start of each function, I have `my_server = redis.Redis(connection_pool=POOL)`. Should I have this at the begging of **both** functions, or just the first one (in case I only need to instantiate it once)?

Comment: what most people do is to have a function that returns a redis instance when called. So that way, you don't have connection code scattered all over